# Play Google TTS file in the same browser window

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I am playing an audio file using Google TTS ([Hello World Example](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20world)) on a link's click in my website. Right now the target window is a new window. I want the playback to happen on the same window (with an embedded player maybe or just the audio file playing with no controls visible)

Can someone please help me on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is code if your site was asp.net(c#)
use it on page load or button click

```
Response.Write("<EMBED runat='server' src='http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=%22+" + your Text + "'" + " hidden='true' volume='100' loop='FALSE' autostart='true'></EMBED>");
```